# If a postdoc is interested to apply for a future professorship in his/her current institution. What should she/he do in the postdoc research period?

Tags: job-search, postdocs, cv, job

Based on the discussion in a previous question
[Apply for assistant/associate professor at same institution as postdoc?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29695/apply-for-assistant-associate-professor-at-same-institution-as-postdoc)
If someone is interested to apply for a future assistant/associate professorship in the same institution where one is currently working as a postdoc/research scientist. What one should do in his early stages of postdoc research to build independent scientific contribution so that the institution of interest would like to include him/her in its faculty members?

Comment: What country is the institution in?

Comment: Say it is a US research major university.

Comment: What one should do is no different than what one should do to get a professorship anywhere else: do the best work one can, hope for the best, and (as explained in the question you linked to) assume this is most likely not going to happen. This question is essentially a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually my question is an extension to the previously mentioned one. My core question here is how to develop an independent research that can be distinguished from the posdoc mentor main work. So, it will be possible to have a new contribution when applying for assistant professor position in the future.

Comment: @DanRomik if your eventual job search is limited to the current university, then your strategy should be different.

Comment: @Wind yes I understand what you're trying to achieve, and I wish you the best of luck, but the "new contribution" aspect is largely irrelevant. If you do sufficiently good work, and are lucky enough to have the stars align in your favor in several other ways, you will be hired by the postdoc school; in the other 98-99% of cases, sadly that won't happen. There is no particular winning strategy that will increase your odds any more than the obvious strategy of doing the best work you can. That's my opinion based on my experience. If StrongBad or others disagree, I'm happy to hear their thoughts.

Comment: @DanRomik I disagree.  I have heard of two cases where internal faculty hires faced difficulty because their work was too similar to the work of the professor who was previously their supervisor.  In one case, the internal hire was denied tenure.  In the other case, the supervisor was promoted to administration.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Indeed, duplication of research area has prevented us from hiring many good candidates, including at least one former postdoc that I can think of now.  Maybe the OP wants to focus the question on this aspect, and say what field they are in and how much overlap there is with their current supervisor.  (It's much easier to do different research from your mentor in math, say, than in some lab science.)

Comment: So, in case of an engineering postdoc using computational approaches for certain practical applications, how is it likely that she/he can conduct a research project distinguished from the main work of his mentor (either by using similar techniques for different applications, or by using different techniques/methods for the same applications), so he/she can try to avoid the duplication issue?

Comment: Even if you have done the best you can, if there are no openings for a new faculty at the end of your postdoc, you will have to apply elsewhere. I think it is more likely for a postdoc to stay as a postdoc at the same university than for a postdoc to progress the ranks at the same university.

Answer (score 3):

I could write a book about this, as I'm sure many faculty members could! My answer involves two major points: political reconnaissance and becoming intellectually self-assured.

First, I suggest you make some good acquaintances in the faculty beyond your PI and get an honest opinion on what it might take to be able to join it. The comments to your question about duplication are potentially valid, IMO, but the degree to which it matters or the precise interpretation is going to depend on the personalities involved, the political climate in your institution, and the tenure/promotion manual of the department/college/university.

Of course, you just can't show up to the bar one evening and ask people point-blank after a couple of drinks :) You need to genuinely show interest in the direction and health of the department over an extended period of time, and possibly get more involved in departmental decision making, administration, or teaching. Diplomacy and politicking is key here.

Even if you don't get to formally ask some questions, thinking about them can help you detect subtle signs of their answers in the communications between faculty. E.g., Is there a prevailing mood that your PI's research area is popular among the faculty? Is it an area that the department even wants to expand? Do they even expect to be hiring anyone in the next 2-3 years? Is your PI going to be your champion and partner (you'll probably need that!) or is he/she going to perceive your presence as a colleague to be a source of departmental competition for lab space, students, money, attention, etc. I've known some PIs manipulate and exploit their post-docs so that they essentially become trapped in their position as essentially cheap technical labor (your experience with the PIs work is very valuable to them). There is usually a *lot* more going on privately that will affect the eventual decision to hire anyone new. Use the chance to reconnoiter and make alliances to your advantage while you are this close to the action. It may become clear that it will be much better for you to make a clean break, and you might get a stronger recommendation from your PI as a result.

Second, you have to plan early with your PI to show off your contributions above and beyond what the PI has done in establishing this particular line of research. If, between that and chats with other friends or colleagues, you can't figure out what you are or will be doing in the very near future that distinguishes your creative input and future personal direction as independent, then you won't be successful in communicating that in your writing or presentation to hirers.

IMO, your PhD study was supposed to be the time where you figured out a line of independent thought that you take forward during post-doc work. You should be dedicating time to develop those ideas into plans for projects over the next decade or more. You should use that to (diplomatically and respectfully) push your own agenda: you must stake out your space in your work and your perception in your community. Anything less and you are frankly setting yourself up for being labeled (fairly or unfairly) as not "faculty material". Gossip works the same in academia as it does in any walk of life, don't be fooled by the intellectualism.

If your PI is dominating your direction of work then get some side projects going of your own (even secretly), but discuss with your PI how to get more involved in the planning before it's too late! You won't last a minute in faculty-level academia without being assertive and developing healthy skills of persuasion. Fakers will be called out quickly, so get ready to defend your plans.

In any case, don't get your hopes up for staying on at the same institution. An academic career path is already extremely tough to succeed in without restricting your future options like this. I know first-hand how it is hard to imagine leaving a place you know and like but there are usually other good opportunities out there that you'll need to better appreciate. Stay brave and open-minded.